# cell phone number and provider, how are they linked?

Tags: design

I am curious, technically, how a cell phone number is linked with a provider.

For example, I know the IMEI and CCID numbers were used when I activated my last phone, how does this link with my phone number?

The idea behind this, is that I have a phone number that I do not want to use at the moment.  I can cancel my current service, but I do not want to lose the number. I want it to be "parked". There are sites that do this, such as [ParkMyCellPhone](http://www.parkmycellphone.com). What are the technical  aspects behind this? Could it be done using, say, Asterisk PBX?

Also, if there is a better SE website for this please let me know I know it doesn't fit well here but I could not find a better option.